# Can not style an "active" link with css

Tags: html, css

I want to style the "active" link .login but it do not work. Where is the problem?

```css
.active {
  color: rgb(0, 148, 199);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <span id="logo"></span>
  <span id="navTop">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">.welcome</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.register</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">.login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
  <span id="navBottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">.overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.feature</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.videos</a></li>
        </ul>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's all you have? cuz it works for me - https://jsfiddle.net/6n31zbst/

Comment: I find that the default link styles override most css. You should be more specific and use a.active.

Comment: It seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/5f0v3hnm/. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: check out [this](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-add-a-class-or-id-to-an-anchor-tag-in-HTML.php) site for examples on how to color anchor tags. it looks like you should specify `active:link` and `active:hover:` for the active class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work fine. I would suggest you have some other css rule that is overriding this.

You can test this by adding !important to the css rule and see if it solves the problem. Then you need to track down what style is overriding it.

e.g.

```
.active {
    color: rgb(0, 148, 199)!important;
}
```

```css
.active {
    color: rgb(0, 148, 199);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<span id="logo"></span>
<span id="navTop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">.welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">.register</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">.login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">.contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
<span id="navBottom">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">.overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">.feature</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">.videos</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
</div>
```